# Where do the ethers come from when sending ethers with .send() function in ethereum contract

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity

I'm learning ethereum token contract following [here](https://ethereum.org/token). I'm confused by the code below:

```
function sell(uint amount) returns (uint revenue){
if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) throw;        // checks if the sender has enough to sell
balanceOf[this] += amount;                         // adds the amount to owner's balance
balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                   // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
revenue = amount * sellPrice;
if (!msg.sender.send(revenue)) {                   // sends ether to the seller: it's important
    throw;                                         // to do this last to prevent recursion attacks
} else {
    Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);             // executes an event reflecting on the change
    return revenue;                                 // ends function and returns
}
```

}

the line *msg.sender.send(revenue)* means to send ethers to the seller. My question is:

Does the ethers to be sent come from msg.sender or from the token contract?
I think they comes from msg.sender. However the msg.sender is actually in behalf of the seller, right? That makes the seller sends himself ethers. May I know how to understand this. And then how do I make a contract send ethers back to a user account automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests to figure out this question. I find out that the ethers which are sent to destination address are from the token contract instance address.

I was confused before because I didn't understand how a contract instance gains ethers after being constructed. Now I get to know that the contract instance gains ethers when an account invokes a method marked by keyword *payable* of the contract. When the invoking happens the ethers are sent to the contract address at the meantime. In the [demo token code](https://ethereum.org/token), it is the method buy() who plays the role to send ethers to the contract address.

I'm new for learning ethereum contract. There probably still are some mistakes about what I realize. Please let me know if there are. Appreciate that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.send` is a function belonging to the `address` type, where the address on which it's called is the recipient. The ETH being sent comes from the smart contract.

You can also use `transfer` and `call`. [This article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-transfer-vs-send-vs-call-function-64c92cfc878a) does a good job of explaining the differences.

Examples:

```
address recipient = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

// using transfer
recipient.transfer(revenue);

// using call
recipient.call{value: revenue}("");
```